# How do I configure host/ip on sparkjava?

Tags: java, jetty, spark-java

If I have multiple IP addresses on my server and would like to assign each spark app to a different IP address/host, how is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method in the Spark `Service` class ([javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.sparkjava/spark-core/latest/spark/Service.html)) that sets the IP address that your Spark server listens on.

> `public Service ipAddress(String ipAddress)`
>
> Set the IP address that Spark should listen on. If not called the default address is '0.0.0.0'. This has to be called before any route mapping is done.

---

If you wanted these apps to run in the same JVM, it looks like you do this by instantiating multiple `Service` onjects.  The javadoc says:

> `Service` represents a Spark server "session". If a user wants multiple 'Sparks' in his application the method `ignite()` should be statically imported and used to create instances.

Comment: Caveat: the above answer is gleaned from reading, not experience.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Spark.ipAddress("my.IP.address");`
Reference: [javadoc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.sparkjava/spark-core/latest/spark/Spark.html#ipAddress-java.lang.String-)